# Confusion about definition of ergodicity in Markov Chains

Tags: definition, markov-chains, markov-process

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity) I found the following section on ergodicity

> **Ergodicity**
>
> A state i is said to be ergodic if it is aperiodic and positive
> recurrent (*). In other words, a state i is ergodic if it is recurrent,
> has a period of 1, and has finite mean recurrence time. If all states
> in an irreducible Markov chain are ergodic, then the chain is said to
> be ergodic.[dubious – discuss]
>
> It can be shown that a finite state irreducible Markov chain is
> ergodic if it has an aperiodic state. More generally, a Markov chain
> is ergodic if there is a number N such that any state can be reached
> from any other state in any number of steps less or equal to a number
> N (**). In case of a fully connected transition matrix, where all
> transitions have a non-zero probability, this condition is fulfilled
> with N = 1.
>
> A Markov chain with more than one state and just one out-going
> transition per state is either not irreducible or not aperiodic, hence
> cannot be ergodic.

I added the asterisks myself. What's confusing to me is that (**) seems much less strict than (*) because it doesn't mention periodicity. For example the transition matrix
$$P=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}$$
seems to fullfil (**) because every state can reach any other state in 3 steps. Is (**) correct? Am I reading this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the definition given there is confusing.
(**) is more general than (*).

Actually there are two definitions there. This reflects the fact that there are several inequivalent definitions of ergodicity for Markov chains in the literature.

Some authors ask for a single absorbing class, which is sligthly more general than (**), others say that a chain is ergodic iff it is both irreducible, positively recurrent and aperiodic, which is (*).

Comment: Ah great, they use two different definitions without mentioning it in two neighbouring paragraphs. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!